# use FormDataParam in netbeans

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm trying to use the FormDataParam to upload a file to the glassfish server but I can't figure out how to import it.

When I add the Jersey library with netbeans (Right Click on Librairies and Add Library) there is no such package **org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart**.

And when I try to download Jersey from the website the jar does not contain this package.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes someone in my university found a solution (for netbeans). It's in french but I can try and translate it here to put it as an answer

Comment: np, found it myself too :)